# output random numbers in three different rows

Tags: vba, excel, random

I am working on random numbers VBA and the below code picks a name from sheet2 and copies to sheet 1 and I can repeat these steps to pick 3 different names from that list. This code does a fantastic job when all the three names are in three consecutive rows but fails to pick 3 different names when they are in row 5th, row 10th and row 15th. Can someone help me pick three different names and put them in rows that are 5 rows apart? (1st name in 1st row, 2nd name in 5th row and 3rd name in 15th row) I am new to VBA!

```
Sub DDQ1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim source, destination As Range
Set source = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A60:A81")
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
Set destination = ActiveSheet.Range("B53")
ReDim randoms(1 To source.Rows.Count)
destrow = 0
For i = 1 To destination.Rows.Count
 If destination(i) = "" Then: destrow = i: Exit For
Next i
If destrow = 0 Then: MsgBox "no more room in destination range": Exit Sub
For i = 1 To UBound(randoms): randoms(i) = Rnd(): Next i
ipick = 0: tries = 0
Do While ipick = 0 And tries < UBound(randoms)
tries = tries + 1
minrnd = WorksheetFunction.Min(randoms)
For i = 1 To UBound(randoms)
If randoms(i) = minrnd Then
  picked_before = False
  For j = 1 To destrow - 1
    If source(i) = destination(j) Then: picked_before = True: randoms(i) =        2: Exit For
  Next j
  If Not picked_before Then: ipick = i
  Exit For
End If
Next i
Loop
If ipick = 0 Then: MsgBox "no more unique name possible to pick": Exit Sub
destination(destrow) = source(ipick)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but `Dim source, destination As Range` will make destination a range, but source as variant. You need `Dim source as Range, destination As Range`

Comment: A little formatting would go a long way here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, if you change the line

```
For i = 1 To destination.Rows.Count
```

to

```
For i = 1 To destination.Rows.Count Step 5
```

this should work. Though when I tried it I also had to make the Destination range bigger than just "B53". I put in "B53:B99"

Comment: Hi Rob.. Thank you for responding. I tried to put in your suggestion but it is not working. The problem is range can not get bigger. I have certain restrictions to get bigger range. To re-iterate, macro should pull three different names (mutually exclusive) from a range and put those three names in three different rows that are 5 rows apart.

Comment: When I try to run your code (as given) I get one value in Cell B53 then the error message "no more room in destination range. This is because your range is ONE cell, so one it has copied one thing, there is no more room. At the very least the range has to be B53:B63 to fit in three items of data, five cells apart.

Comment: Ok! I am using "Call" function in a separate macro to call this macro thrice so that I get three different names. I am new to VBA and the method I am using might be very primitive. Now I am realizing it will not work with this methodology. Is there a better way?

Comment: I realise you are calling it three times but, when I call it the second time, if the range is just "B53", it will not add any more data. I don't really see the issue with making the range "B53:B63", it will only change the three cells you want it to change.